# (react) bundle.js takes a long time to load when editing a react compenent and reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, web-frontend

in any react project it doesn't matter how small and simple the code is. when any changes are made the website's reloading takes a long time 30 seconds or more. when I open the network tab i find that bundle.js file is loading.

I have tried to reinstall yarn and react-scripts
I have also delted eslint which lead to nothing
also updated my intel macbook pro to the latest mac os software (Monterey)

[network tab loading bundle.js in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND50O.png)

Comment: same problem here, do you solve this problem?

Comment: I formatted my Mac and It worked. I also found out that sometimes it happens because I using a hotspot connection.